# ASP.NET Core - Configurable routing

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core 3.1 app. This app has an "Admin" area. I've put this area in it's own library to use in other apps. In my other app, I can currently access the "Admin" area by visiting `https://{domain}/_admin`. I want to reuse/share this library with other apps in my company. Now, other devs in my company have built other apps. So, I expect the `_admin` path may cause conflicts. For that reason, I want to make that part of the route configurable. Currently, I have the following

**appsettings.json**

```
{
  "Miscellaneous": {
    "AdminRoot":"_admin"
  }
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```
...
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
  ...
  app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
  {
    var adminRoot = Configuration["Miscellaneous:AdminRoot"];
    adminRoot = String.IsNullOrEmpty(adminRoot) ? "_admin" : adminRoot;

    endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute(
      name: "Admin",
      areaName: "Admin",
      pattern: (adminRoot + "/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}")
    );
  }
  ...
}
...
```

**AdminController.cs**

```
[Area("Admin")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
  public IActionResult Index()
  {
    return View();
  }

  [Route("~/api/user-permissions")]
  public IActionResult LoadUserPermissions()
  {
    var permissions = GetPermissions();
    return Json(permissions);
  }
}
```

This approach uses [convention-based routing][1]. At the same time, my Admin tool also has it's own REST API. For that reason, I want to mix convention-based routing with [attribute routing][2]. Basically, I want to have routes like `/_admin/api/user-permissions`. As this route demonstrates, the `_admin` creates a challenge if I add a `Route` attribute in my API since it's a configured value.

I thought if I used the `~` it would be relative to the area. However, I get a 404 when I try this approach. Is there a way to dynamically set *parts* of a route? For example, I would love to be able to either:

- Use an approach relative to the area or
- Use an attribute like `[Route("{Configuration["Miscellaneous:AdminRoot"]}/api/user-permissions")]`

I'm not finding a way to accomplish what I'm trying to do. Is there a way to do this? Please note, my Admin area is much more complex. I've tried to isolate this question to my actual problem. In addition, I'm looking to have a configurable approach for the sake of learning. For that reason, I'm not interested in solutions like changing "_admin" to a random value like a GUID or something. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been reviewing this for several hours. Essentially, since the one parameter is pulled from configuration, the routing requires convention based routing. However, some names, like those URL-friendly names that include dashes are invalid method names in C#. The way around this is use the following:

- Rely on convention-based routing
- Use attributes other than `Route` in the controllers. On actions, use the `ActionName` attribute.